# Create a vector where a function is applied to every nth element

Tags: r

> I want to create a vector of size say 1000 such that every element is zero except every 4th element which I apply a function X(z) to. Every 4th element should give a different value of X(z).

Originally I had the code below which gives me 1000 elements of different values of X(z). But I only want it to apply to every 4th element, and the others to be 0.

```
 replicate(1000,X(1))
```

I then created a list of a thousand 0s and add X(1) to the 4th element by

```
a<-replicate(1000,0)
a[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,TRUE)] <- a[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,TRUE)]+X(1)
```

But this gives me the SAME value of X(1) for every 4th element. I want the function to run differently for each element. Is there a more eloquent way of doing so than my thinking?

Comment: What about `sapply(1:1000, function(i) if (i%%4 == 0) X(1) else 0)`

Comment: Yes this works, thanks!

Comment: You can also do `x <- 1:1000
(x %% 4 == 0)*x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To functionalize the comment from @qdread for any `n`:

```
# create function X to extract first element from vector y
X <- function(y) y[1]

# create function to apply function X to nth element of vector v
my_fn <- function(v, n) {
sapply(v, function(i) if (i%%n == 0) X else 0)
}
```